# "This often happened" vs "this happened often"

Tags: grammar, word-order

My editor changed "this often happened" to "this happened often."

I checked on [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20often%20happened%2C%20this%20happened%20often&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20often%20happened%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20happened%20often%3B%2Cc0) and discovered that their frequency is almost the same.

Maybe the order doesn't matter? Or one is more common than the other in certain situations?

Comment: Possibly. Without more context it's hard to say why your editor made that suggestion. Was that the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Often' is an adverb, and while a few say adverbs should go before the verb, the order doesn't *usually* matter.

Or, the order doesn't matter, *usually*.

Or even, the order *usually* doesn't matter!

There are three common positions for adverbs in a sentence:

1. before the subject
2. between the subject and the verb, or immediately after 'be' as a main verb
3. at the end of the clause.

A similar example involving these three positions has already been answered on [this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences):

> - Why did they target us specifically?
> - Why did they target specifically us?
> - Why did they specifically target us?

A broader question about adverb position was also answered on a neighbouring SE site [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb).