# Word order - automatically before or after verb?

Tags: sentence-construction

which sentence does sound better for a native speaker?

- A list update process automatically selects accounts that need an intervention.
- A list update process selects accounts automatically that need an intervention.
- A list update process selects automatically accounts that need an intervention.

Comment: my bet is the middle option

Comment: I vote for the first option. I don't think putting _automatically_ between _accounts_ and the relative clause (in second opton) is a good idea. Also, putting _automatically_ before a noun (_accounts_)  is no good choice as the adverb doesn't describe the noun. But let's wait and see what native speakers will tell us.

Comment: I wrote the first sentence originally but it started to sound too slavic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic was addressed in [another ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences). "Broadly speaking, the adverb is preceding the word it's modifying."

Thus, the first sentence is correct.

> 1. A list update process automatically selects accounts that need an intervention.

Ok.

> 2. A list update process selects accounts automatically that need an intervention.

No.

It would be alright if you dropped the final clause, "A list update process selects accounts automatically", because placing an adverb at the end of a sentence can be an option.

> 3. A list update process selects automatically accounts that need an intervention.

No.