# Can I put the adverb "exponentially" after the intransitive main verb "grown" when the auxiliary verb "had" precedes the intransitive main verb?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Can I put the adverb *"exponentially"* after the intransitive main verb *"grown"* when the auxiliary verb *"had"* precedes the intransitive main verb *"grown"*? (auxiliary verb + intransitive main verb + adverb) Here is the example sentence.

> The corn had grown exponentially since last year.

Or should the adverb come after the auxiliary verb and before the intransitive main verb?

> The corn had exponentially grown since last year.

Comment: I much prefer the first option.  But what research have you done to try to find out?

Comment: @Jim
I read through other answers to questions that are very similar to my question; however, the answers were not spot on. I also tried other websites, but there were too many answers that conflict with each other.

Comment: Tommy, ok good, what would help us answer them, is to update your question summarizing what you found, describe why what you found conflicts, and what led you to believe that you ***couldn’t*** write it like you propose.  Something like:  I was taught a rule that says, “blah blah blah” and when I looked at <site A> it said <one thing> but <site B> said <a different thing>.  As far as I can tell they are both reputable sites. How can either of them be wrong?

Comment: This may help https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences

Comment: @Jim
Thanks, but no thanks. I'd rather not spend that much time compiling that much information in an attempt to obtain an answer to a grammar question. How would that information help you or anyone else answer it? I believe I might have a better idea. The first sentence of your first comment was, "I much prefer the first option." Why do you prefer the first option? Is it because it sounds natural, or do you have information based on grammar rules?

Comment: @tgdavies
Thanks for the suggestion. I already read through that page, but it doesn't specifically address how intransitive verbs play a part.

Comment: I have no idea what an intransitive verb is, but I can assure you that the first option is correct :-)

Comment: @tgdavies
An intransitive verb is a verb that has no direct object. I appreciate the time you've taken to answer my question, but if you get a chance, could you let me know how you know the first option is correct? Is it because it sounds natural, or is there a different reason?

Comment: Just because it sounds natural (there may well be reasons why the second isn't good grammar, but I am unaware of them)

Comment: But that is what you're supposed to do -- summarize your findings. The Tour page in help tells you this: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Answer (score 2):

The first option *sounds* better to my ears, but either option is grammatically correct. But I would go so far as to say the second option is somewhat awkward. I think when you have an adverb that is five syllables long, you usually put it after the verb. And by putting the adverb after the verb, you're putting slightly more emphasis on the adverb by virtue of its placement at the very end of a phrase. I think "exponentially" warrants emphasis.

Comment: Agreed. You've already stated the verb; now you're talking about how it is different than its usual sense. Reading the sentence aloud naturally your ears pick up the emphasis in the adverb.

Comment: Yes, if you are talking about several things that have grown exponentially, then the 2nd option sounds OK to me. For example: `Peanuts had exponentially grown, soybeans had exponentially grown, and corn had exponentially grown.` The audience is familiar with the shocking idea of something growing exponentially, so it's no longer necessary to emphasize it anymore -- let it split the noun and verb.